# Store the result of a function in a list python

Tags: python, string, list, function, store

**Intro**
I got a function that parse the output from the daemon socket. I use it to catch the keys pressed on a IR remote.

```
def getKey():
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(128)
        data = data.strip()

        if (len(data) > 0):
            break

    words = data.split()
    return words[2], words[1]

key = getKey()
print(key)
```

**Problem**
Function always returns a single string object

Output:

```
1
<class string>
2
<class string>
7
<class string>
```

**Question**
How can I store all those string objects to a single list object for further use?

Like so:

```
[1,2,7]
<class list>
```

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append

Comment: list.append does not work, it always retruns a list with a single object inside.


I tried this:
`def getKey():
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(128)
        data = data.strip()

        if (len(data) > 0):
            break

    words = data.split()
    return words[2], words[1]

key = getKey()
#print(key)
key_log = []

key_log.append(key)`

and it does not works because it returns :

`[1]
<class list>
[2]
<class list>
[7]
<class list>`

Comment: The way the program is written, the function returns a tuple of two strings, not a string object, so I don't understand the output you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def getKey():
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(128)
        data = data.strip()

        if (len(data) > 0):
            break

    words = data.split()
    return words[2], words[1]

keys = []
keys.append(getKey())
keys.append(getKey())
keys.append(getKey())
print(keys)
```

Comment: it seems to works, but it prints objects only after list contains 3 items, like this:
`Socket connection established!
Ready...
['BTN_1', 'BTN_5', 'BTN_9']
['BTN_8', 'BTN_7', 'BTN_5']`

Comment: Print whenever you want its just an example